# Dimension Reduction Using Correlation Weighted Linear Aggregation

Tags: correlation, dimensionality-reduction

Is there an existing use in the literature of linearly aggregating standardized regressors by their correlation coefficient with the dependent variable in order to create a synthetic regressor?

For instance,
$x^* = \rho_{x_1,y}x_1 +\dots +\rho_{x_n,y}x_n$

Alternatively, what is the most analogous technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a literature on correlation weights (which ignore collinearity) vs. OLS regression weights. Recently, for example, see [Dana & Dawes 2004](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.3102/10769986029003317). When assumptions hold, you can't beat OLS regression weights for in-sample prediction, but OLS weights are only superior for out-pf-sample predictions when both sample size and true R square for the dependent variable are both high.
Dana, J., & Dawes, R. M. (2004). The superiority of simple alternatives to regression for social science predictions. Journal of Educational and Behavioral Statistics, 29(3), 317-331.